# Which cluster methodology should I use for a multidimensional dataset?

Tags: multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis

I am trying to create clusters of countries with a dataset quite heterogeneous (the data I have on countries goes from median age to disposable income, including education levels).

How should I approach this problem?

I read some interesting papers on clustering, using K-means for instance, but it seems those algorithms are mostly used when there are two sets of variables, not 30 like in my case, and when the variables are comparable (it might be though to try to cluster countries with such diversity in the data).

Should I normalise some of the data? Should I just focus on fewer indicators to avoid this multidimensional issue? Use spectral clustering first?

Thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Create a "similarity metric". Probably just a weight to all your measurements, but you might build in some corrections for population size and so on. Then you can only have low hundreds of countries, so most brute force methods will work. Hierarchical clustering would be my first point of call, and that will tell you if the data is inherently clustered.

If all the data is quantitative, you can normalise on 0 - 1 (lowest country is 0, highest is 1), then take eigenvectors. Then plot out the first two axes in eigenspace. That will give another visual fix on clusters.

If it's not clustered, however, it's better to admit that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All the data is indeed quantitative.

Comment: Wanted to add details... So should I normalise everything first, then look for the similarity metric? The thing I don't understand is I will have the 30 or so indicators normalised but how will the similarity metric be computed in that case? I ll need to compute it for each indicator with regard to every other indicator? So I ll need to do it 30*29*... times? Or is there something I am missing here? Sorry if it's a beginner question, I ve done econometrics and stats but a while ago :-) I will look into hierarchical clustering, thanks!

Comment: The methods are separate. Either build a "similarity metric" which is something like "give weight of 2.0 to income, 5.0 to education, 1.5 to median age", and so on, but could also do things like "ignore the two most extreme differences". So the function is "similarity(countrya, countryb)" and returns 0.0 if the two countries are identical and a high value if they have nothing in common. Or use the eigenvector (sometimes call principal components) method.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I ll try both approaches and see which one gives the best results. Do you have any keyword I could look into to assign weight to variables? I have found a super interesting article on W-k-means and a way to apply weights to variables but it's a theoretical paper (Automated Variable Weighting in k-Means Type Clustering) and I have no idea how to apply this to my dataset. Thanks a lot for the replies!